# How to obtain a legal license for Mac OS X

Tags: mac, license

I am thinking about adding another partition to my current pc and adding OSX. I know its doable but wanted to obtain a legal license to the software.

The only thing I see available online is an upgrade option. Is there anything else? Or is that all I can obtain legally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I called 1800-MY-APPLE and was able to obtain a license to OSX for $21

Comment: Did you tell them you're trying to build a hackintosh? Your license is most certainly not legal on non-Apple hardware, as per the EULA.

Comment: Yep. From [the license](http://store.apple.com/Catalog/US/Images/MacOSX.htm): "This License allows you to install and use one copy of the Apple Software on a single **Apple-labeled computer** at a time." (emphasis added)

Comment: @Karan, yes I did. The CSR didn't care he only mentioned that he couldn't offer any suggestions on how to obtain the download and how to create the hackintosh.